# Switching from asp.net Identity 1 to 2, our OnValidateIdentity code no longer works

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We recently upgraded from Identity 1.0 to 2.0 on our .net mvc 5 project.

I found out the "remember me" cookie was no longer working, so I found the code below in an example:

```
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                    .OnValidateIdentity<FrontendUserManager, FrontendUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), 
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user)
                            => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
                    )
```

Problem is our old code is somewhat different, since we check for user.Deleted and user.Enabled properties:

```
OnValidateIdentity = context =>
        {
            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();
            string userID = context.Identity.GetUserId();
            var user = uow.FrontendUserRepository.GetByID(userID);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Deleted || !user.Enabled)
                { 
                context.RejectIdentity();
                context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut();
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

I have no idea on how to make our old code work in Identity 2.0, and we need to add more checks soon, like user.EnabledToDate, and so on.

Where/how should I implement these validation checks?